# Add Product Tags to order items on WooCommerce email notifications

Tags: php, woocommerce, product, orders, email-notifications

With the help of this forum I have managed to add a custom field to the woocommerce order emails using this code snippet:

```
`/**
* Add a custom field & product tag (in an order) to the emails
*/
add_action('woocommerce_order_item_meta_end', 'email_confirmation_display_order_items', 10, 4);

function email_confirmation_display_order_items($item_id, $item, $order, $plain_text) {

   $product = $item->get_product();

   if ( empty( $product ) ) {
    return false;
   }

   $date = get_field( 'course_dates', $product->get_id() );

   if ( !empty( $date ) ) {
    echo '<div style="font-size:12px;"><br>Course Date(s): '. $date .'</div>';
}

 }
```

I would now like to improve upon that and also add 'product tag' to those emails (I am using the product tag to specify the location of events).

Having looked around the forum and played around a little I have come up with the following which is clearly inorrect as it breaks the site:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_item_meta_end', 'email_confirmation_display_product_tag', 10, 4 );
function email_confirmation_display_product_tag($order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email) {
   $items = $order->get_items();
   foreach ( $items as $item ) { 
    $product_tag = $item['product_tag'];
   }    
   if ( !empty($product_tag ) ) {
    echo '<div style="font-size:12px;">Location: '. $product_tag .'</div>';
}
}
```

Any assitance here to get me on the right path would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some mistakes in your code, try the following instead:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_item_meta_end', 'email_confirmation_display_product_tag', 10, 4 );
function email_confirmation_display_product_tag($item_id, $item, $order, $plain_text) {
    // Only on email notifications and "line" items
    if( is_wc_endpoint_url() || ! $item->is_type('line_item') ) return;

    // Get the product tag(s) for this order item
    $term_names = wp_get_post_terms( $item->get_product_id(), 'product_tag', array('fields' => 'names') );  

    // Display
    if ( count($term_names ) > 0 ) {
        printf( '<div style="font-size:12px;"><br>%s: %s</div>', __('Location', 'woocommerce'), reset($term_names) );
    }
}
```

It should work.

---

You should merge both functions in one as they use the same hook, like:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_item_meta_end', 'email_confirmation_display_custom_data', 20, 4 );
function email_confirmation_display_custom_data($item_id, $item, $order, $plain_text) {
    // Only on email notifications and "line" items
    if( is_wc_endpoint_url() || ! $item->is_type('line_item') ) return;

    $product = $item->get_product(); // get the WC_Product object

    // Get the ACF 'course_dates' field value
    if ( $date = get_field( 'course_dates', $product->get_id() ) ) {
        printf( '<div style="font-size:12px;"><br>%s: %s</div>', __('Course Date(s)', 'woocommerce'), $date );
    }

    // Get the product tag(s) for this order item
    $term_names = wp_get_post_terms( $item->get_product_id(), 'product_tag', array('fields' => 'names') );  

    // Display
    if ( count($term_names ) > 0 ) {
        printf( '<div style="font-size:12px;"><br>%s: %s</div>', __('Location', 'woocommerce'), reset($term_names) );
    }
}
```

Be sure to remove other related functions before. It should work.

Comment: Thank you very much for this however for some reason it does not appear to work? On running it through a code checker it highlights an issue on line 7:    // Get the product tag(s) for this order item
    $term_names[] = wp_get_post_terms( $item->get_product_id(), 'product_tag' array('fields' => 'names') );    Parse error: syntax error, unexpected token "array", expecting ")"  could this be the problem?

Comment: @Fitzy007 Oups!, sorry there was a missing comma. I have updated the code.

Comment: that has solved that problem and now the code runs however the output is: Location: Array - and not the actual product tag?